# graphDB consistency check not working while protege is showing expected results

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, graphdb

My Ontology is simple (made in Protege). I've made

- *Manga* and *Manhwa* classes disjoint to each other.
- Any individual that is *Comic + Japan* is a *Manga*.
- Any individual that is *Comic + South Korea* is a *Manhwa*.

Now I created an individual "*SL*" that belongs to class *Manhwa* and hasCountry *Japan*. This combination should not be possible. **Protege reasoner (HermiT) will throw error for this.** (expected behaviour)

**But when I import this into GraphDb, it doesn't show any error.** On the contrary GraphDB will tell that *"SL"* belongs to both *Manga* and *Manhwa* classes and hasCountry both *Japan* and *South Korea*. I've enabled consistency checks and SHACL validation when creating this repository and am using OWL-max ruleset.

**What else should I do to turn on consistency check in GraphDB that will give error?**

```
@prefix : <http://comi.test/#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://comi.test/#> .

<http://comi.test/#> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://comi.test/#hasCountry
:hasCountry rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                     owl:FunctionalProperty ;
            rdfs:domain :Comic ;
            rdfs:range :Country .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://comi.test/#Comic
:Comic rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://comi.test/#Country
:Country rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://comi.test/#Manga
:Manga rdf:type owl:Class ;
       owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Comic
                                                  [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                    owl:onProperty :hasCountry ;
                                                    owl:hasValue :Japan
                                                  ]
                                                ) ;
                             rdf:type owl:Class
                           ] ;
       rdfs:subClassOf :Comic ;
       owl:disjointWith :Manhwa .


###  http://comi.test/#Manhwa
:Manhwa rdf:type owl:Class ;
        owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Comic
                                                   [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                     owl:onProperty :hasCountry ;
                                                     owl:hasValue :South_Korea
                                                   ]
                                                 ) ;
                              rdf:type owl:Class
                            ] ;
        rdfs:subClassOf :Comic .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://comi.test/#Japan
:Japan rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                :Country .


###  http://comi.test/#SL
:SL rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
             :Manhwa ;
    :hasCountry :Japan .


###  http://comi.test/#South_Korea
:South_Korea rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                      :Country .


###  http://comi.test/#hxh
:hxh rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
              :Comic ;
     :hasCountry :Japan .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: owl-max ruleset does not have any consistency checking rules. You may try using owl2rl insead. Please, check the documentaton at https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/reasoning.html#consistency-checks to find out what is supported. Also it is not clear what shacl shapes/rules you were using to detect inconsistencies over your data/model....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use owl2rl ruleset** in graphDB, as other rulesets don't have consistency checking built into them.